# Smooth curve in Bokeh

Tags: python, visualization, plotting

I have been trying to plot my data from a cvs file with [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) but I couldn't find a smoothing option to smooth my graph curve.

Is there any in `bokeh.plotting` for this task? If not, how else should I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

`bokeh` library internally uses `_glyph_function` function to plot, if you take a look at their [source code](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/master/bokeh/plotting/helpers.py) and which takes help from basic numpy, scipy library for defining arrays and other stuff and this so goes for curve smoothing too. So better do achieve this via [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/signal.html#filtering).